# A problem on matrices : Sum of elements of skew-matrix

Tags: matrices

> If $A=[a_{ij}]$ is a skew-symmetric matrix, then write the value of $$ \sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}$$

My doubt is that what is the meaning of $ \sum_i \sum_j ?$ Is it the same as $\sum_{ij}?$

Please offer your assistance.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, sum over all pairs $(i.j)$ for $1 \le i \le n$ and $1 \le j \le n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the notaion. It is easier to understand on concrete example. Say $n=3$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^3\sum\limits_{j=1}^3a_{ij}
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^3(a_{i1}+a_{i2}+a_{i3})\\
&=(a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{13})+(a_{21}+a_{22}+a_{23})+(a_{31}+a_{32}+a_{33})\\
&=(a_{11}+a_{12}+a_{13}+a_{21}+a_{22}+a_{23}+a_{31}+a_{32}+a_{33})\\
&=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^3 a_{ij}
\end{align}
$$

As for the original problem. Elements of the diagonal are zeros (why?). So you need to perform calculations only for nondiagonal entries. Divide them into pairs $a_{ij}+a_{ji}$, recall definition of skew symmetric matrix and conclude...

Comment: okay, i know that. so are they one and the same?

Comment: all pairs gives the same sum

Comment: no that si not what i asked is $\Sigma_i \Sigma_j [aij] = \Sigma_{i j} [aij]$?

Comment: yes it is $\phantom{}$